# Loading svg with webpack url-loader returns js file

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack

I'm attempting to load an svg image with webpack like so:

```
const logo = require('./images/logo-white.svg')
```

Keep in mind this works for all of our other images, they're all just not svg.
No matter what combination of loaders I use, when I load up the url or data-uri it puts in, the source looks like this:

```
module.exports = 'data-uri-that-is-the-actual-image'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a "solution," really it's a terrible hack, but considering I haven't been able to find any other way, here it is:

```js
function webpackSvgFixer(svg) {
  // Remove data...base64, headers, leaving just the base64
  svg = /data.*base64,(.*)/.exec(svg)[1]; 
  // Convert base64 to string, then remove module.exports = and quotes
  return /module\.exports = "(.*)"/.exec(atob(svg))[1];
};
const logo = webpackSvgFixer(require('./images/logo-white.svg'))
```